# Is it possible to broadcast over Bluetooth LE without targeting a device?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building an app with Xamarin and MvvmCross that requires the use of Bluetooth LE, but this question is pertaining to Bluetooth LE technology in general, not specific to any platform.

Reading tutorials, I noticed that when a device transmits data over Bluetooth LE, it's always targeting another Bluetooth device, so that no other device can acquire the transmission.

My question is, is it mandatory to target a device? Or can I just blindly broadcast the transmission and let any Bluetooth device acquire the transmission?

I am targeting both Android and iOS platforms, if that is relevant.

**EDIT**

Also, is it bad practice to blindly broadcast sensitive data? Does targeting a device guarantee security/data privacy?

Comment: Look up "bluetooth low energy peripheral mode" which allows for the device to behave like a beacon (ibeacon/eddystone). If your question is different than what that mode provides, please provide details on differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not relavant if you use iOS or Android.
The relevant part is the setup of the devices:
One device acts as Master device and can connect to several slave devices.
It is all about the setup and the roles which you allocate.
You can also e.g. let a thermometer broadcast data and all BLE Smartphones which has access via the Protocal Stack (knows the UUID number) can retrieve data.

Comment: So, if I understood your example correctly, the thermometer (master) can broadcast data to all BLE devices (slaves) that know the same UUID. In other words, it is impossible that ALL the BLE devices can acquire the broadcasted data because they don't all know the UUID (like a device without my app installed). Correct?

Comment: To access a BLE device you need to know the UUID which means for the developer - if you create lets say a gadget with BLE, the user has to install YOUR app to use it. But security algorithms is up to developer - if you only want to grant access with payment or pin you can to this ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It is called bluetooth broadcast or bluetooth advertising. [Check this out](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/bluetooth/ble_advertising)